# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"network")

Tags: java, javax.xml

My pojo:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Network", namespace = "urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg")
@XmlType(name = "Network", namespace = "urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg")
public class Network {
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private NetworkSupportedFeaturesSection supportedFeatures;

    @Valid
    private NetworkFullSiteDiversitySection fullSiteDiversity;

    public NetworkSupportedFeaturesSection getSupportedFeatures() {
        return supportedFeatures;
    }

    public void setSupportedFeatures(NetworkSupportedFeaturesSection supportedFeatures) {
        this.supportedFeatures = supportedFeatures;
    }

    public NetworkFullSiteDiversitySection getFullSiteDiversity() {
        return fullSiteDiversity;
    }

    public void setFullSiteDiversity(NetworkFullSiteDiversitySection fullSiteDiversity) {
        this.fullSiteDiversity = fullSiteDiversity;
    }
}
```

Here my xml:

```
 <network>
    <supportedFeatures>
        <nmsDiversity>ENABLE</nmsDiversity>
        <fullSiteDiversity>ENABLE</fullSiteDiversity>
    </supportedFeatures>
    <fullSiteDiversity>
        <activeDc>DC2</activeDc>
        <active1NGw>My_Teleport_5_GW_Main</active1NGw>
    </fullSiteDiversity>
</network>
```

Here my unit test:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
 @Test
    public void should_throw_exception_with_error_message_when_execute_operation_with_corrupted_parameter2() throws IOException {
        URL url = getClass().getResource(PATH_TO_FULL_SITE_DIVERSITY_RESOURCES + "/network_node.xml");
        Optional<Network> network = convertXMLToObject(url);
    }

    private static Optional<Network> convertXMLToObject(URL url) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Network.class);
            Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
            return Optional.of((Network) un.unmarshal(url)); // error here
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

But I get error:

```
2023-05-30 15:11:57.705 ERROR [NetworkWebServiceTest:main] unexpected element (uri:"", local:"network"). Expected elements are <{urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg}FullSiteDiversity>,<{urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg}Network>,<{urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg}SupportedFeatures>
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"network"). Expected elements are <{urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg}FullSiteDiversity>,<{urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg}Network>,<{urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg}SupportedFeatures>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:712) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:232) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:227) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:94) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1117) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:542) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:524) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:?]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:228) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:199) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at com.myproject.integrationtest.server.ws.NetworkWebServiceTest.convertXMLToObject(NetworkWebServiceTest.java:106) ~[test-classes/:?]
    at com.myproject.integrationtest.server.ws.NetworkWebServiceTest.should_throw_exception_with_error_message_when_execute_operation_with_corrupted_parameter2(NetworkWebServiceTest.java:98) ~[test-classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69) ~[junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232) ~[junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55) ~[junit-rt.jar:?]
```

Comment: Your XML does not contain any namespace declaration, yet your Java code does. The XML should have looked something like `<network xmlns="urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg">...</network>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is not matching what you have configured in @XmlRootElement and @XmlType annotations.

In annotations, you have `Network` with uppercase `N` and `urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg` namespace.

In the XML sample, you are using element `network` with lower-case `n` and no namespace. Try to either align the XML to the annotations, or annotations to the reality of your XML file.

Based on the error message, other elements might have incorrect case as well.
`Expected elements are <{urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg}FullSiteDiversity>,<{urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg}Network>,<{urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg}SupportedFeatures>`

Try this:

```xml
<Network xmlns="urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg">
    <SupportedFeatures>
        <nmsDiversity>ENABLE</nmsDiversity>
        <fullSiteDiversity>ENABLE</fullSiteDiversity>
    </SupportedFeatures>
    <FullSiteDiversity>
        <activeDc>DC2</activeDc>
        <active1NGw>My_Teleport_5_GW_Main</active1NGw>
    </FullSiteDiversity>
</Network>
```